# My suffix is a common girl's name, My whole is a chocolaty shame

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix is small and round in form
- My suffix is a common girl's name
- My infix is a way to inform
- My whole is a chocolaty shame

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Nutella

My prefix is small and round in form

> Nut

My suffix is a common girl's name

> Ella

My infix is a way to inform

> Tell

My whole is a chocolaty shame

> Nutella = a brand of sweetened hazelnut cocoa spread (very tasty but not very healthy).

Comment: Also it could be a "chocolatey shame" because it's not chocolate; it's hazelnut.

Comment: It has chocolate in its ingredients...

Comment: Cocoa, I think, @Jaques